# Vue import causing cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object error

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I am currently migrating a HTML template to Vue.
Now I started to import the Javascript files in the main.js file stored inside `src`.

**My file looks like the following:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

import pageLoader from "./assets/js/global/page-loader";
import tooltips from "./assets/js/global/tooltips";

Vue.use(pageLoader);
Vue.use(tooltips);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

Every Javascript file is located inside the `src/js` folder

But once I run the application I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
    at Module.eval (webpack-internal:///./src/assets/js/utils/plugins.js:56)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/assets/js/utils/plugins.js:57)
    at Module../src/assets/js/utils/plugins.js (app.js:1579)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/assets/js/global/tooltips.js:1)
    at Object../src/assets/js/global/tooltips.js (app.js:1556)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:15)
```

The whole Projects can be seen on github on the following link: [Link to github](https://github.com/d4ne/xanoty)

What is causing this error? I would appreciate any kind of help to fix my issue.

Comment: Please provide all relevant information within the question itself. Links to external code repositories are not an appropriate replacement

Comment: The problem with this is the error is calling out the plugins file which is only required by the tooltips.js file. So it would actually require me to provide a wall of code.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with focus on the _"minimal"_ part

Answer (score 0):

Your files aren't exporting the functions that Vue is trying to use.

What you need to do is export the function you have located in your file.

Please see this guide to exporting functions in VueJs: https://medium.com/js-dojo/a-beginners-guide-to-exports-in-es6-af27b5a621d0

This will help you understand how you need to export functions from these files that Vue will use to run.

Comment: So i have to export the functions thats a good information so far. But how would I use the Named Exports on the following function: plugins.createTooltip in this file: https://github.com/d4ne/xanoty/blob/main/client/src/assets/js/global/tooltips.js

Comment: Encapsulating this plugin data out into its own folder is likely not how you want to do it. I suggest just pulling that logic into your main.js file, and it will work. Bypassing the import stuff. You usually just import functions, and callbacks